# The intersection of an infinite number of prime ideals in a ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the ring of integers of a number field, $\{\mathfrak{p}_i,\,i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ a sequence of <strike>two-by-two</strike> pairwise distinct prime ideals. Does it follow that$$\bigcap_i \mathfrak{p}_i = \{0\}?$$

Comment: what do you mean by a sequence of two-by-two distinct prime ideals?

Comment: @user114539 I don't see what it could mean besides $i \neq j \implies \mathfrak{p}_i \neq \mathfrak{p}_j$.

Comment: Now the meaning has been made precise by Jyrki.

Comment: I was wondering about the meaning of *two-by-two* myself. But I agree with Najib Idrissi that this is the likely intended meaning. If the OP disagrees, he should, of course, roll it back and explain.

Comment: I believe "two-by-two distinct" is a translation from the French "deux-à-deux distincts"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true. If $I$ denotes your ideal then $I \subseteq \mathfrak p_i$ for each $i$. Suppose that $I$ is not the zero ideal. If $I= \mathfrak q_1 \dots \mathfrak q_j$ is the decomposition of $I$ as a product of prime ideals, then $ \mathfrak q_1 \dots \mathfrak q_j \subseteq \mathfrak p_i$ implies that $\mathfrak q_{r_i} \subseteq \mathfrak p_i$ for some $1 \leq r_i \leq j$, because $\mathfrak p_i$ is a prime ideal. Since $\mathcal O$ has dimension $1$, we actually have $\mathfrak q_{r_i} = \mathfrak p_i$. But since there are infinitely many $i$'s and finitely many possible choices for $r_i$, there are two distinct $i, i'$ with $r_i = r_i'$; but then $\mathfrak p_i = \mathfrak p_{i'}$ which contradicts the assumption made on the $\mathfrak p$'s.

Comment: This works for $\mathcal O$ a Dedekind domain.

Comment: @user26857 Indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be any ideal in $\mathcal{O}$. For $\alpha$ in $A$, $\alpha$ satisfies a monic polynomial of smallest degree, say $\alpha^n+b_1\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots+b_n=0$ with $b_n\neq 0$. Then $b_n=\alpha(-\alpha^{n-1}-b_1\alpha^{n-2}-\cdots-b_{n-1})$, which implies that the ideal containing $\alpha$ contains some non-zero rational integer $b_n$.

In particular, each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_i$ contains a prime integer in $\mathbb{Z}$.

If $\cap_i\mathfrak{p}_i$ is non-zero ideal, then it will contain an integer $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, and hence $n$ will be divisible by infinitely many prime integers  (chosen from $\mathfrak{p}_i\cap\mathbb{Z}$), 
 in $\mathbb{Z}$, a contradiction.

---

(Modified answer after the comment from Jyrki.)

Comment: The elements of $\mathfrak{p_i}$ need not be divisible by the prime generating the intersection $\mathfrak{p}_i\cap\Bbb{Z}$. For example $1+i$ is not divisible by $2$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ even though $(1+i)\Bbb{Z}[i]\cap\Bbb{Z}=2\Bbb{Z}$. However, AFAICT your proof idea can be saved by observing that if the intersection $I=\bigcap_i\mathfrak{p}_i$ is a non-zero ideal, then it contains a rational integer $n>0$. And that $n$ then is an element of all the intersections $\mathfrak{p}_i\cap\Bbb{Z}$, and thus divisible by infinitely many primes.

Comment: Jyrki: I agree with your comment. Thanks for noticing me my mistake. Realizing that this mathztack is a good platform for discussion of basics and better understandings.

Comment: It is also worth adding to my previous comment that the same rational prime $p$ can only generate the intersection $\mathfrak{p}_i\cap\Bbb{Z}$ for **finitely many distinct prime ideals** $\mathfrak{p}_i$. The argument needs this, because otherwise it could be possible that finitely many rational primes might "cover" infinitely many prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$. This is relatively basic fact from algebraic number theory, but I should have realized the need to include this part.

Comment: yes, I agree with this, this is an important "finiteness" property on ring of integers. Hence in previous answer, I had written simply "infinitely many primes".  I will write better and better proof as per your comments.

Comment: (Although not hard to see it) I think you have to explain why "Any prime ideal in a number field contains a (unique up to $\pm 1$) prime integer in $\mathbb{Z}$."

Comment: If $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, then $\alpha^n+a_1\alpha^{n-1}+\cdots + a_{n-1}\alpha+a_n=0$, $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, simplifying this, $\alpha( \alpha^{n-1}+a_1\alpha^{n-2}+\cdots + a_{n-1})=-a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$. This means, mutiplying to any algebraic integer $\alpha$ by a suitable algebraic integer $\beta$, we can move in $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, every ideal in $\mathcal{O}$ contains integers. In particular, every prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}$ contains a prime integer. If a prime ideal contains two distinct primes, then it will contain $1$!

Comment: Well, I wanted to say "you have to explain *in your answer*", not as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of ideals is an ideal. Since yours is divisible by infinitely many primes, it must be that it has no presentation as a product of primes. But in a Dedekind domain, every non-zero ideal has a **unique** expression as the **finite** product of prime ideals (to some power). Hence it must be that your ideal is the only ideal not covered by this theorem:  the zero ideal.